# Android Studio : Unable to add a new class or any file to a project

Tags: android-studio, readonly, readonly-attribute

My Android was working perfectly and was able to add a new xml,activity or any new file to my project. Until recently, it gives an error whenever I add a new class or any new file. It always says:

> Unable to parse template "Class" Error message: Cannot modify a
>   read-only directory
>   'C:\Users\jay\Desktop\CurLoc\app\src\main\java\com\example\jay\curloc'.

I already tried to change the attribute of the folder where my project is located by unchecking  Read-Only box in the Properties. I also restart my computer and Android Studio over and over again and refresh the project but nothing works. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After spending countless hours trying to solve the problem I uninstalled Android Studio and installed it again, this solved the problem. I think it's a bug in Android Studio