# Unable to parse template "Class" Error message: This template did not produce a Java class or an interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-17

Please help me, whenever I'm creating a new class in IntelliJ
It give me a popup box cannot create class

I tried my directory marking it as 'Sources Root'(got from stackOverflow), but still I cannot resolve my problem.

Currently I'm using Linux(14.04, 64-bit)-OS.
IntelliJ version-->Intellij IDEA 2017.1.3

I know my problem statements end's up in 2 lines..but this is the only what I could post
[image: Screenshort]

Comment: Never seen such a thing from IntelliJ in the 13 years I've been using it.  Did you do a clean install?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374605/android-studio-unable-to-add-a-new-class-or-any-file-to-a-project

Comment: duffymo  yes, I reinstalled it twice

Comment: I had the same problem, and for whatever reason, the files that the IDE uses to define how to create a class, interface, singleton, etc., were missing. Look in the "C:\Users\YOURUSERID\.IntelliJIdea201X.X/config/fileTemplate‌​s/internal" directory, and if there are no files there, you need to add them. For the "Singleton.java" file, that does NOT reside inside of the 'internal' subdirectory, but in the 'fileTemplates' parent directory. If you don't have the files to copy back, you'll probably have to reinstall IJ, so that it generates those files.

Comment: finally I resolved my problem, by reinstalling it.

Comment: I don't get why it was closed as "unclear". This question is perfectly clear. Other closing reasons might apply though.

Comment: Stumbled over the same issue. Found a solution here (Fred comment worked for me) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206922365-Unable-to-parse-template-Class-Error-message-This-template-did-not-produce-a-Java-class-or-an-interface-during-New-Java-Class

Comment: This question is perfectly clear, and should be re-opened; especially in light of the fact that this particular IntelliJ problem seems to happen to quite a few people.  At least until JetBrains fix this, it's appropriate for Stack Overflow to have the answer to this (not just a link to a comment elsewhere).

Comment: Sort of solution - copy paste templates from Android Studio. Details in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534524/unable-to-parse-template-class-error-whenever-i-try-to-open-a-new-java-class

Comment: SOLUTION: Run 32 bit edition Idea - all templates will be available. Copy it in x32, then paste it in template editor for x64 edition.

Comment: try to run IntelliJ Idea as administrator